# Couting number of documents in a MongoObservable.Collection

Tags: angular, meteor, rxjs

I'm using rxjs MongoObservable.Collection in my Meteor app and can't find out a simple way to get the number of docs in my collection.

In the following code my `loadData()` method works fine when there are docs in my collection, but as the Observable is never filled with any data in case of an empty collection I can't figure out how to manage this case. Any ideas?

File summary.collection.ts:

```js
export const Summaries = new MongoObservable.Collection<Summary>('summary');
```

File summary.publish.ts:

```js
Meteor.publish('summaries', () => {
  return Summaries.collection.find();
});
```

File summary.component.ts:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'summary',
  template,
})
export class SummaryPage {
  loadData() {
    Meteor.subscribe('summaries');
    this.summariesModel = Summaries.find()
      .debounce(() => Observable.interval(500));

    this.summariesModel.subscribe(summaries => {
      summaries.forEach(summary => {
        if (summary.length === 0)
          this.state = 'empty'; // <== never reach this point
        else
          this.state = 'loaded';
      });
    });

    this.summariesModel.zone();
  } 
}
```

File summary.html:

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let model of summariesModel | async">
      <td> {{model.country}} </td>
      <td> {{model.customer}} </td>
    </tr>
```

**Edit:** To make it clearer, I call this loadData() method many times, and every time I actually pass a different query, like Summaries.find({customer: 'XYZ Ltd.').

I use `this.state` in the template (html) in order to provide 3 different states (via *ngIf): **empty** (displaying a 'There is no data for this customer'); **loading** and **loaded**.

So there is no use to me to wait infinitely to appear something in this query.

Also, as a workaround (or maybe this is the only solution) I created a method in the server that returns the total count of docs given a specific query. And, in the client side, I had to make this:

```ts
asyncSummariesCount(query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Meteor.call('getSummariesCount', query, (err, count) => {
      if (err) count = 0;
      resolve(count);
    });
  });
}

async loadData() {
...
  if (await this.asyncSummariesCount(query) === 0) {
    this.state = 'empty';
    return;
  }
...
}
```

It works pretty fine, but as the client has access to the entire published collection, it should be easier to get the total count of docs.

Comment: Looks like you are modifying your `SummaryPage` instance `state` member with the last `summary` document in your collection? If so, why not just initializing it to `'empty'`?

Answer (score 0):

Will async with else block will help you? Here is an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JZf8BaIfFceJx8HQHGi8

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <div *ngIf="obs$ | async; else elseBlock">not empty</div>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>empty</ng-template>
      </div>
    `,
   })
   export class App {
    s = new Subject();
    obs$;

    constructor() {
       this.obs$ = this.s.asObservable();
       // publish after 5 sec
       setTimeout(()=>
            {this.s.next('aaa');}
        , 5000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I edit my question as I missed to explain that there are 3 states in my case, empty, loading and loaded. This solution of yours would work only if I had 2 states, loaded or not-loaded.

Comment: how u identify loading state?

Comment: State 'loading' is when it starts querying the database (find()), then there are 2 next possible states: 'loaded' when it finishes loading or 'empty' if there is nothing in this specific query.

Comment: ok, so the observable should use startwith() operator to emit a loading state. the component will display this loading in "if" happy path while it is loading